# Why is ffmpeg executable so much faster than using libfdk_aac directly?

Tags: audio, encoding, ffmpeg, aac

When I encode a wav file to AAC using the ffmpeg executable (using libfdk_aac and setting -threads 1), the process completes several times faster than when I use the AAC encoding example provided by the libfdk_aac library itself. I looked at the code and the central loop in libfdk_aac is almost identical to the aac_encode_frame method in the ffmpeg source.

Anyone know why the executable would be so much faster? I'm looking into compilation options but we're talking like 8x speedup so I don't think it's just putting -O3 on there... Does ffmpeg encode multiple buffers at once even when there is only one thread?

Comment: Sounds like difference in single- vs multi-thread...